# unexpected store exception at every start

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, reboot

My girlfriend just bought a brand new **Acer Swift 3 SF314-57** and she is getting an **unexpected store exception** at every reboot or new start. Sometimes even after waking up the computer. 
This might be due to the fact I ghosted the hard drive from her former computer (an HP Pavillon TPN-C125 also on windows 10 64bits) but I uninstalled every HP driver and brand-specific drivers and reinstalled the officials' driver from Acer websites.

`sfc /scannow` doesn't find anything

`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` says that the operation has been successful

she doesn't use any antivirus except defender

the computer still boots after a while (up to 3 minutes) but it's getting really annoying.

do you have any further ideas? the goal is to keep the same image cause she has some specifics software from her school and those are pretty harsh to install and have only one license by student

Comment: Can you provide us a screenshot of the exception?

Comment: Those errors are to be expected whenever users do what you did, pushed an image taken from an OEM installation (the OEM license doesn't allow it) into a totally different machine. I believe it activated because the new machine has already a registered valid serial for the same or similar Windows version but that doesn't mean that it won't have other issues or errors like the one you're experiencing.

Comment: @user931000 I have exactly same issue with exact same model. My laptop came with win 10 home version. I had older acer pc with win 10 pro. I created a usb installer from other laptop and installed windows 10 pro on it and applied my digital license. I didnt install from a backup or image. Is it supposed to produce error?

Comment: Have you found reason and any solution? Please let me know

Comment: Yeah, it was a material problem with the NVMe. anyway, I put the computer in warranty. thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, we sent the laptop back to ACER who told us that it was in fact a driver issue with the newer generation of processors and the compatibility with the M.2 SSDs (i7-1065G7). This laptop was one of the first to have one of that new generation of processors.

ACER changed the SSD and then everything was ok.